# Can't unit test a context provider? Empty div output

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library, react-context

I have an app component that uses a context provider from my external library and I'm struggling to unit test it.

```
import {SomeContext} from 'my-external-library';

const MyApp = ({children}) => (
    <Suspense fallback={Fallback}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <SomeContext>
                {/* App code in here */}
                {children}
            </SomeContext>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Suspense>
    
);
```

Now... I have confirmed that I can render everything wrapped by the `<SomeContext>` within my React Testing Library test with `debug()`, but when I add the wrapper... I simply get an empty div `<div />` rendered...

This is the point that I am stuck.

I have attempted to `jest.mock` out the `SomeContext` without success.

```
it('Should render', () => {
    jest.mock('my-external-library', () => ({
        SomeContext: jest.fn((props) => <>{props.children}</>) // I know this is likely wrong
    }));

    let component;

    await act(async () => {
        component = await render(
            <MyApp>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </MyApp>
        );
        console.log('inside the act');
        component.debug();
    })

    console.log('outside the act');
    await component.debug();
});
```

The context provider wrapper itself has the structure:

```
const Context = createContext({ /* Some data */ });

const SomeContext = ({children}) => {
    // Some logic

    return <Context.Provider value={value}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
}
```

Comment: First of all, `App` does not have a `children` prop in your code.

Comment: @LinDu My bad. I was focussed more on getting the test and provider code in place. Have added the children now.